# Serial Communication in C# incorrect parameter

Tags: c#, serial-port

when I type in data and hit send, I receive the following message **"incorrect parameter"**. Is there any errors/ exceptions/ problems in the following program.

Another question: Is it good idea to use a structure for implementing the protocol between a controller attached through the serial port?

Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
    // PortName, BaudRate, Parity, DataBits, StopBits
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serial.PortName = "COM1";
        serial.BaudRate = 9600;
        serial.DataBits = 8;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ports = serial.PortName;
        PortCB.Items.Add(ports);
        PortCB.SelectedIndex = 0;
        Close.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    //button to open serial port
    private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Open.IsEnabled = false;
        Close.IsEnabled = true;
        try
        {
            serial.PortName = PortCB.Text;
            serial.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    //button to close serial port
    private void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
    {
        Open.IsEnabled = true;
        Close.IsEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            serial.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    //send message typed in a text box 
    private void Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   
    {
        try
        {
            if(serial.IsOpen)
            {
                serial.WriteLine(SendTB.Text);
                SendTB.Clear();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    //show message receive received in a text block
    private void Receive_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
    {
        try
        {
            if (serial.IsOpen)
            {
                ReceiveTB.Text = serial.ReadExisting();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    //close the serial port if at all open
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
    {
        if(serial.IsOpen)
            serial.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your controller send this message? "Incorrect parameter"

Comment: No Sir, I get this message from the code above when I try to transmit the data to the serial port. At the moment I am using an emulator for the serial port. I am waiting for the serial to usb cable to arrive, i have ordered one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `WriteLine` method works incorrect. Try to change your `Send_Click` method to the following:

```
private void Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   
{
    try
    {
        if(serial.IsOpen)
        {
            serial.Write(SendTB.Text + "\n");
            SendTB.Clear();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

> Is it good idea to use a structure for implementing the protocol between a controller attached through the serial port?

I'm not sure what do you mean, but I'll try to answer: You can transmit data through the serial port either in ASCII representation or as raw bytes flow. Theoretically, it should be possible to serialize, transmit and deserialize your structure, but I cannot say exactly how to do this.

Comment: convert each parameter to string, transmit it serially as ascii. at the receiver, perform the reverse operation. one may consider trimming the string and adding special char between 2 diff data

Comment: write and writeln are essentially the same thing except, the next string will be printed on a new line. the error does not occur when a cable is used. perhaps, some problem with the emulator.